# Are dual constructors allowed in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, constructor, typescript2.0

Are dual constructors allowed in typescript?

```
export class Userdetails {
  private username: string = null;

  constructor (details: user) {
    this.username = details.username;
  }

  constructor () {
  }

  myOtherFunc(){}
}
```

Comment: what happens if you try that?

Comment: I get an error saying multiple constructors are not allowed. I am using TS 2.1.6

Comment: well, that answers your question! Though the link in the other comment could be useful

Comment: The link says constructor overload is possible. It does not seem to work for me. I am trying this `constructor ();
  constructor (details: user) {}`

Comment: `The link says constructor overload is possible` - but your code looks nothing like the code in the linked question

Comment: Ok. Got it. I used an option params in constructor to work across this. thnks a ton.